# Cannot find the issue in my query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone find the issue with this SQL query?

```
"SELECT SUM(ROUND(IFNULL(mgap_ska_growth,0)))+
        SUM(ROUND(IFNULL(mgap_ska_recovery,0))) AS acctotal 
 FROM mgap_ska 
 WHERE account_manager_id = '$account_manager_id' AND mgap_status = 1";
```

The issue is somewhere in the last half because I can remove everything before the WHERE and it works fine. I dont get any return otherwise.

Ive checked the DB and the conditions are being met and Ive replaced the variable $aacount_manager_id with an actual account manger id number and it still doesn't work.

All fields match as required.

Can you see where my brain fart is?

Comment: Do you have any records with an mgap_status of 1?

Comment: yes there are numerous records that match

Comment: I assume you mean that you remove the WHERE clause and it works fine.  And what do you mean when you say you "get no return otherwise"? The reult is zero?

Comment: Im printing out 'acctotal' and nothing is being printing...not zero, just nothing. yes it works fine without the WHERE portion.

Comment: Well, have you tried simply `select * from mgap_ska where account_manager_id = (value here)`? Maybe you just *think* you have matches.

Comment: yes...I said such in my post.

Answer (score 2):

Without access to your database, it's hard to say exactly what is wrong.

You can follow these steps to identify the problem:

1. Run the query without the WHERE clause (You've already done this and found some records.)
2. Run the query with the following WHERE clause:

   **WHERE account_manager_id = '$account_manager_id';**

   If you don't find anything, you found your problem. If you do find records, move on to step 3.
3. Run the query with the following WHERE clause:

   **WHERE mgap_status = 1";**

If you don't get anything back, you found the problem. If you do, it means that there aren't any records for the account manager you're specifying with an mgap_status of 1 that have an "acctotal".

If you are still unable to determine what is wrong, run the query without the acctotal calculation:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM mgap_ska 
 WHERE account_manager_id = '$account_manager_id' AND mgap_status = 1";
```

If this works, then the problem is with your acctotal calculation (for the manager and status you've specified).

If acctotal is your issue, try this:

```
"SELECT SUM(mgap_ska_growth + mgap_ska_recovery) AS acctotal 
 FROM mgap_ska 
 WHERE account_manager_id = '$account_manager_id' AND mgap_status = 1";
```

I'm sure you know this, but it's worth saying anyway. When you run into problems with a query or a piece of code, simplify it as much as possible. Once you get the simple bit working, layer on another piece of complexity, get it working, and so on until you get the whole problem solved.

Comment: Thats just it...I have narrowed it down to mgap_status and I have records with '1' in my field. mgap_status is an INT

Comment: I added one other query to try in your troubleshooting. Do you get any results if you eliminate the acctotal calc?

Comment: ok it definitely looks to be in the addition of the two sums. Any advice on the best way to approach it? Im just adding the SUM of two columns together. Both are DEC data types.

Comment: Try sum(mgap_ska_growth + mgap_ska_recovery). See updated answer.

Comment: found it! Darn NULL values...used IFNULL and she fired right up! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is there any records with account manager id is equal to the string value "$account_manager_id" ? cause if not, if account_manager_id is an integer, and the *$account_manager_id* is a variable holding some integer, then you need to write:

```
"SELECT SUM(ROUND(IFNULL(mgap_ska_growth,0)))+
    SUM(ROUND(IFNULL(mgap_ska_recovery,0))) AS acctotal 
 FROM mgap_ska 
 WHERE account_manager_id = " + $account_manager_id + " AND mgap_status = 1";
```

Comment: It's stated that when the parameter is substituted with an actual id, it still produces a wrong output. Besides, interpreting the string parameter as an integer to check for equality is more resource eating, it does not end up on invalid result set if an integer value is passed as a string.

Comment: @rekaszeru, that's exactly what I'd expect if the OP is changing the query to include `WHERE account_manager_id = '1'`

Comment: Yes,  what exactly did he change it to?  If he changed it to `Where account_manager_id = xxx` where xxx is an integer that exists, he would get results. But he says he gets no results.

Comment: I have replaced the variable with an actual number and it still doesn't work.

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with your query, so if you are getting no results with an actual number in the where clause, but get actual results without the where clause, then there is no record in the table with that number as the account_manager_id